# How to let vim show BOM as <feff>

Tags: vim

When I look at a file on one of our servers I see something like this:

```
<feff>sku;qty
productsku;1
```

When I download the file and open it with vi I don't see the `<feff>`

When I do `:e ++bin` I can see the `<feff>` but I also see ^M now

```
<feff>sku;qty^M
productsku;1^M
```

But I don't want to set the `^M`. I just want to see the `<feff>`.
Another example is `<80>` which I had in another file.

How can I set up vim to show me those special chars?

~ EDIT ~

The command `vi --version` tells me the following:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Aug  4 2010 07:21:08)
```

It also says that the system-vimrc-file is `/etc/vimrc` which has the following content:

```
if v:lang =~ "utf8$" || v:lang =~ "UTF-8$"
   set fileencodings=utf-8,latin1
endif

set term=builtin_ansi
set nocompatible    " Use Vim defaults (much better!)
set bs=indent,eol,start     " allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
"set ai         " always set autoindenting on
"set backup     " keep a backup file
set viminfo='20,\"50    " read/write a .viminfo file, don't store more
            " than 50 lines of registers
set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands
if has("autocmd")
  augroup redhat
    " In text files, always limit the width of text to 78 characters
    autocmd BufRead *.txt set tw=78
    " When editing a file, always jump to the last cursor position
    autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal! g'\"" |
    \ endif
  augroup END
endif

if has("cscope") && filereadable("/usr/bin/cscope")
   set csprg=/usr/bin/cscope
   set csto=0
   set cst
   set nocsverb
   " add any database in current directory
   if filereadable("cscope.out")
      cs add cscope.out
   " else add database pointed to by environment
   elseif $CSCOPE_DB != "" 
      cs add $CSCOPE_DB
   endif
   set csverb
endif

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on 
  set hlsearch
endif

if &term=="xterm"
     set t_Co=8
     set t_Sb=^[[4%dm
     set t_Sf=^[[3%dm
endif
```

I copied this and added it to my `~/.vimrc` but none of these changes does what I want. A few things are in if cases so I might have to play around with these too.

Does anyone know if there are other files than the one stated in `vi --version` that will be read when editing a file?

Comment: IMO your desired functionality is reasonable, but unfortunately there isn't any way to achieve it, as far as I know. Vim tries to hide line endings and the BOM (if present) so you can focus on just the text. Best bet is probably to look into the [`'bomb'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'bomb') option; you can make it part of a custom [`'statusline'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'statusline').

Comment: The strange thing is it has to be possible, because I have this behaviour on most of our servers. But I don't know which configuration it is.

The ~/.vimrc is the same as mine so there must be another file the is loaded on the server which has the settings I need

Comment: Hmm, interesting. One possibility that comes to mind is that you might have older versions of vim on your servers which are not BOM-aware, so it ends up being displayed as normal text. I remember when I worked for IBM a while back we had a lot of servers with remarkably old versions of vim/vi (vi 3.1 in one case, IIRC) that were disappointingly light on features.

Comment: On our server we have `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Aug  4 2010 07:21:08)` and on my mac I have `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jul  9 2015 23:58:42)` so they are not too much away from each other

Answer (score 8):

`:help 'bomb'` explains Vim's behavior:

> When Vim reads a file and 'fileencodings' starts with "ucs-bom", a
>     check for the presence of the BOM is done and 'bomb' set accordingly.
>     Unless 'binary' is set, it is removed from the first line, so that you
>     don't see it when editing.

So,

```
:set fencs-=ucs-bom
```

would turn this off, but then the encoding detection is broken, too! According to my experiments, explicit encoding setting (via `:edit ++enc=ucs2-le`) also sets `'bomb'` and removes the `<feff>` mark. So, this avenue leads nowhere.

#### Alternatives

- Editing in binary mode, as you've found out. I wouldn't recommend it, since it has drawbacks.
- Including the indication in the *statusline*. You have to look somewhere else, but it's always visible, not just at the beginning of the document. Highly recommended as the right way™ in Vim. And easy to achieve, too:

```
set statusline+=\ %{&bomb?'BOM':''}
```

Comment: Do you know an editor that can show the BOM in the text itslef?